# HTML / CSS columns overlap

Tags: html, css

I made a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/qsyh2rrq/).

Why does `dice-canvas-container` use the full width of the window and not stop at the start of `attack-canvas-container`?

Is it because both columns are positioned absolute?

```
<div id="attack-container">
    <div id="dice-canvas-container">
         <div id="plyra-dice-canvas"></div>
         <div id="plyrb-dice-canvas"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="attack-canvas-container">
           ..................
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could see some not so good approaches with your code, like why do you position everything with absolute? You just want `dice-canvas-container` and `attack-canvas-container` to be side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suitable with your requirement then you can go with `flex` css instead of `position: absolute`

```css
#attack-container {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: absolute; */
  max-width: 1728px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1047;
  /* float:left; */
  display:flex;
}

#dice-canvas-container {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1428px !important;
  max-height: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* position: absolute; */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 1048;
  /* display: block; */
  /* float:left; */
  background-color: red;
  min-height:150px;
}

#attack-canvas-container {
  @extend %background-gradient;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1048;
  /* position: absolute; */
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  box-shadow:         -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  min-height: 150px;
}

#plyra-dice-canvas,
#plyrb-dice-canvas {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;

  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1428px;
  max-height: 540px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1049;
}
#plyra-dice-canvas {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
#plyrb-dice-canvas {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid $brand-primary;
}
```

```html
        <div id="attack-container">
            <div id="dice-canvas-container">
                <div id="plyra-dice-canvas"></div>
                <div id="plyrb-dice-canvas"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="attack-canvas-container">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Check the updated [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/qsyh2rrq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `position: absolute` (1) with `width: 100%` (2) for both containers in combination with `z-index` (3).

(1) : because of this, both container are absolutely positioned, not relatively.
(2) : since both have 100% width, they will overlap the other one.
(3) : the one with the higher z-index wins the upper hand.

You need to change the absolute positioning and give proper widths to the divs.